# To understand the logic of c language program

Tags: c

```
int main()  
{ 
  printf("%d%d%d", sizeof(3.14f), sizeof(3.14l));    
}
```

OUTPUT --41256

May I know what is the logic behind this output ?

Comment: No logic. The behavior of this is undefined. You have three format specifiers, but passing only two parameters (and the types of the parameters are not matching the format specifiers).

Comment: @EugeneSh. it's UB even before that: calling a function that accepts a variable number of arguments without a prototype in scope is UB.

Comment: Aside from everything else, why not make it easier on yourself and write `"%d %d %d"` so you can at least see where one random number ends and the next one begins?

Comment: You also have the wrong format specifiers for `sizeof` which should be `%zu` .

Comment: Did you really get two `-` signs in a row?  That *is* surprising.

Comment: @SteveSummit there's *undefined behaviour* for you ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, yeah, but if he really *did* get two in a row (if it's not some kind of typo, as I suspect), then I want to know, because it *is* remarkable, even by UB standards.

Comment: @SteveSummit I never was a subscriber to nasal demons or green cats. My guess too is -- unformatted punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

you make an error (3 specifiers and only 2 values).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()  
{ 
  printf("%zu %zu", sizeof(3.14f), sizeof(3.14l));    
  return 0;
}
```

The Output is : "4 16".

"sizeof" of somethings is his size in RAM (memory)
in the example 3.14f is a float so it size is 4 bytes
for the 3.14l is a long double so it size 16 bytes.

Comment: No `%lu` is still not right.  You want `%zu` for type `size_t` as returned by `sizeof`.

Comment: the `%z` specifier was added in C99, so `%lu` it's not a problem (even a don't get an warning), after all thanks!

Comment: I know there are compilers that don't support `z` (as a matter of fact I use one of them), but in that case, `%lu` is *not* the right fix.  `%lu` is just as wrong as `%u`, just as likely to not work.  If you don't have the `z` modifier, the right fix is to explicitly cast to `(unsigned)` or `(unsigned long)` to match the format specifier you choose. (And thanks for fixing.)

Comment: if you want `%lu` (because you are limited to a C89 implementation maybe), convert the value for conformance: `printf("%lu", (long unsigned)sizeof 3.14);`